# Can't import an object saved to file with dput in R

Tags: r, save, restore

Hello I created an list object that contains boot the object returned by the `boot::boot()` function and a summary of results I build on the top of that.

I saved such object to a file using dput. But now I can't regenerate the object using `dget()` or `source()`. I receive this error:

```
bt <- dget(file.choose())
Error in sample.int(n, n * R, replace = TRUE) : object 'R' not found
```

Since I called `boot()` and used dput in another function I suspected that to rebuild a bt object the R variable which was an argumento to `boot()` is required to exist also in the global environment (not the best implementation). So I created such variable in the global:

```
R = 5000
bt <- dget(file.choose())
bt
[1] ""
bt <- source(file.choose())
bt
$value
[1] ""

$visible
[1] TRUE
```

Empty objects!

Any idea?

Here's a link to the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/xceeoewidm87gtv/CFC%20vs%20BRAF.r?dl=0

Comment: It's telling you it cannot find a value for R and we see no such value created so the error message seems accurate and informative.

Comment: I tried to debug this 2 days ago but it has package dependencies that I am not willing to install.  Perhaps you should try to whittle down the file (mostly shorten the data) so the errors are easier to find

Comment: Shortening the data would be useful, but even more useful would be to display the code that was used to create this "structure". When I try to drop the code into a running R session I get the same error and running traceback then shows code that suggests you are using `dplyr` or `maggritr` in the call to `boot`.

Comment: yep magrittr is used into the definition of the statistic function passed to boot. my bad about the packages. The object is pretty simple, is a list with a boot object and a data.frame. Unfortunately the boot object expects R that is a variable defined in a function scope, where I called boot( ). Anyway even providing R in the scope where I call dget or source doesn't fix the problem. I don't get errors or warnings, just an empty value.

Comment: Unfortunately the statistic depends on many custom functions I made...