# R - Error using dput with SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, export, polygon, spatial

I use `dput()` and `dget()` to export and import data. I get an error when I import the exported text file of a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

> Error in parse(file = file, keep.source = keep.source) :
>   MapFrance.txt:161:23: '<' inattendu(e) 160: ), row.names = c(NA,
>   96L), class = "data.frame") 161:     , polygons = list(<
>                              ^

The error doesn't appear when I use a data frame. It works also with a SpatialPointsDataFrame.

The code is :

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

MyDirectory <- "" # fill with the directory

MapFrance <- readOGR(dsn = paste0(MyDirectory, "Departements"),  layer = "DEPARTEMENT")

dput(x = MapFrance, file = paste0(MyDirectory, "MapFrance.txt"))

Load_MapFrance <- dget(file = paste0(MyDirectory, "MapFrance.txt"))
```

The link to the geographic data (a SPH file) :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wksMnkufQPdOfSbhWoZbPKMqlcLcll_j

Comment: [Look at this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161311/how-to-load-the-output-of-dput-into-an-object)